# cant send pdf file with email xcode

Tags: iphone

please help me! I can send image but can't sent pdf file despite i see icon file attachment on email.
My code :

```
MFMailComposeViewController *sendmailview = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    sendmailview.mailComposeDelegate = self;
// I can send image with:   
//    UIImage *roboPic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
//    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(roboPic, 1);
//    [sendmailview addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Default.png"];

// But Can't send pdf file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

       NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"book.pdf"];

    NSMutableData *data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

    [sendmailview addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"book.pdf"];

// I see icon book.pdf when attach,but when i sent mail,mail receiver not see pdf file...

        [self presentModalViewController:sendmailview animated:YES];

    [sendmailview release];
```

Help me........

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFileComponent:@"book.pdf"];
```

instead of

```
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"book.pdf"];
```

Also, data can be `NSData` instead of `NSMutableData`.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

Lastly, have you ensured that the PDF file is present at the path you are referring to? Is the variable data valid?

Comment: Thank you! I did : NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/book.pdf"];
 and it work now! thanks for your help